# Upload file by dragging to browser window in Cappuccino

Tags: javascript, cappuccino, objective-j

Is there anything that has been done by somebody to make it a simple process to upload a file to the server in Cappuccino by dragging it from desktop to the browser window? Are there any built-in features in Cappuccion that let add this functionality easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Deep Drop Upload framework. There hasn't been much development going on in the [main repo](https://github.com/davidcann/deepDropUpload) though. You might prefer [my fork of Deep Drop Upload here](https://github.com/aljungberg/deepDropUpload/commits/flllow) which is cleaned up a little and contains fixes for various browsers.

Note that drag upload does not work in all browsers so Deep Drop Upload also features a 'legacy mode' using a button with roughly the same API as the regular operation.